# 'PKIX path building failed - unable to find valid certification path to requested target' (behind corporate proxy with authenthication)

Tags: java, react-native, gradle, flutter, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying my hand at flutter and react-native (I'm a beginner developer) and I have to build a small prototype for my company, but I can't get past the "run my first app" step due do a certificate error (detailed below).

I am behind a corporate ssl proxy that needs authentication, and we have an internal certificate chain as well. Now, I have zero experiences with certificates overall, so please be mindful of how a beginner would try to solve this.

I've combed the web for solutions and I'm at a loss about some of what I found:

1. Some recommended using the InstallCert java app, but I can't due to proxy reasons and couldn't find a version that lets me set up my username and password for the proxy.
2. Using the keytool to store the certificate into the java cacerts file, but I don't know which of the certificates I should install: The repository's (dl.google.com ?), or my company's.
3. Would it be possible to download that .pom file and store it somewhere so it wouldn't need to access the internet to run? I can access that dl.google.com domain just fine and download it.

Below I've pasted my build.gradle file and the exact error.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Error running Gradle:
>   ProcessException: Process "C:\src\teste1\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: It should not hurt to store both the company's cert and the Jfrog cert in your cacerts. I've been in a similar situation years ago, and I believe the company's cert was a root certificate which took care of everything. So I would recommend importing both certificates with `keytool`, kill any existing Gradle daemons, and try your build again.

Answer (score 0):

I stepped on the same issue running `flutter run` on Windows 10 behind a corporate internet proxy, but without authentication in this case.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/andro
>   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/too
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building faile
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.1-4818971.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/bui
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/aap
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building faile
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target

The following workaround worked for me. Hope it helps somebody!

1. Open the internet browser of your choice.
2. Navigate to https://dl.google.com
   (note: it redirects to https://www.google.com/chrome/).
3. Manually download and store cert to dev box.

   > Navigate to the URL via your internet browser.
   >   Click on the Lock icon in the address bar of the browser.
   >   Click on the Certificate menu item in the opened context menu.
   >   Change tab to Details.
   >   Click "Copy to file..." CTA.
   >   Export cert using the export wizard.
4. Run `certlm.msc` on the dev box.
5. Import previously downloaded `.cer` file.
6. Rerun `flutter run`.

Comment: what do you mean by "3. Manually download and store cert to dev box." How will you do it?

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ please find the newly added instruction of how to do that in the answer.

Comment: I encountered an error while importing the .cer file. It say's "an error occurred during the opening of the enterprise trust store" I don't know if Im importing it right.

Comment: @ilovejavaAJ it might be due to your permissions, also try this one https://serverfault.com/a/604544/446091 as it talks about "Local Computer" folder